# Entity Framework Power Tools Reverse Engineer Code First into a folder

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I'm using Entity Framework Power Tools Reverse Engineer Code First to generate my POCO classes, mapping files, and context from the database. I was able to change the T4 templates to generate a different namespace based on my database schema, but I am not able to find how to create a folder based on the tables schema and place the related POCO classes in the folder.

Could somebody help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The folders for the model (and the mappings) are hard-coded in the tool. Reverse-engineering EfPowerTools.dll shows the following lines in method `ReverseEngineerCodeFirst` of `ReverseEngineerCodeFirstHandler`:

```
string str3 = str2 + ".Models";
string path1_1 = Path.Combine(directory.FullName, "Models");
string str4 = str3 + ".Mapping";
string path1_2 = Path.Combine(path1_1, "Mapping");
```

So, too bad, you can't change the name and location of these folders.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

As mentioned in other answer this approach won't work. So the answer is no longer applied.

<s>You can try resolving the output path and create a folder by doing the following:</s>

```
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>

var efHost = (EfTextTemplateHost)Host;
var outputPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(efHost.TemplateFile), "YourFolder");

if (!Directory.Exists(outputPath))         
  Directory.CreateDirectory(outputPath);
```

Now to output to different folder you can try using the *GenerationEnvironment* similar to this:

```
<#@ dte processor="T4Toolbox.DteProcessor" #>
<#@ TransformationContext processor="T4Toolbox.TransformationContextProcessor" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="T4Toolbox" #>

ProcessOutputTemplate template = new ProcessOutputTemplate(this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString());
template.Output.File = outputPath;
template.Render();
this.GenerationEnvironment.Clear();
```

Note: this approach requires the T4 Toolbox installed in the VS 2012/13 - http://www.olegsych.com/t4toolbox/ (http://www.olegsych.com/t4toolbox/gettingstarted/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to add another answer as I have tried the approach suggested in my previous one and that didn't work. I have changed EF Power Tools in order to output files to different folder or project.

1. You need to install the following EF Power Tools Extension (https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/khorvat/EFPowerToolsEx)
2. Use this code to accomplish the export

   ```
   var efHost = (EfTextTemplateHost)Host;
   var code = new CodeGenerationTools(this);   
   var dte = efHost.DTE;
   EnvDTE.Project ModelProject = null;

   foreach(EnvDTE.Project dteProject in dte.Solution)
   {
       if (dteProject.Name.Equals("YourModelProjectName"))
           ModelProject = dteProject;
   }

   var ModelProjectDirectory = new FileInfo(ModelProject.FullName).Directory;
   var ModelProjectNamespace = (string)ModelProject.Properties.Item("RootNamespace").Value;
   string ModelNameSpace = ModelProjectNamespace + ".Model";
   string outputPath = Path.Combine(ModelProjectDirectory + ModelExportPath + @"Generated\I" + efHost.EntityType.Name + ".cs"); 

   Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(outputPath));
   if (ModelProject.DTE.SourceControl.IsItemUnderSCC(outputPath) && !ModelProject.DTE.SourceControl.IsItemCheckedOut(outputPath))
       ModelProject.DTE.SourceControl.CheckOutItem(outputPath);
   File.WriteAllText(outputPath, this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString());
   ModelProject.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(outputPath);
   this.GenerationEnvironment.Clear();
   ```

With this you will be able to export output to another file, folder and even a project.

Comment: I am getting to errors when I try running it: 1) 'Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Utilities.EfTextTemplateHost' does not contain a definition for 'DTE' and 2) The name 'ModelExportPath' does not exist in the current context. I basically copied and pasted everything where the original var efHost = (EFTextTemplateHost)Host line is.

Comment: What EF version are you using?

Comment: I believe the latest one, 6.3.1 with VS 2013

Comment: It looks like @khorvat 's changes didn't make it to the EF Power tool release Beta 4. And yes it is true that those(Model, Mapping) directories are hard coded in the Handler.So Either you have to change the code by hand and recompile the ddl to get it working or just move the files around by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the [EFPowerTool extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) to support the namespace based directory structure creation. Created a pull [request](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/vendettamit/efdev/contribution/8721) on EF 6.x project at codeplex. Also I have created an [experimental branch](https://github.com/vendettamit/EFPowerTool) on github for testing purpose.(*There surely are room for fixes/enhancement which can be added and tested before sending updated pull request*)

You can download the extension installer with the proposed fix from [here](https://github.com/vendettamit/EFPowerTool)(see install dir in source).