# EF Power Tools - reverse engineer code first into different folders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working with EntityFramework 6 and I'm trying to find a tool which generate my models from my database without an edmx file (code first with existing database).
I mean those classes :

```
public class util_emailMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<util_email>
{
    public util_emailMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.id_Util_Email);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.email)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("util_email", "MyDatabase");
        this.Property(t => t.id_Util_Email).HasColumnName("id_Util_Email");
        this.Property(t => t.email).HasColumnName("email");
        this.Property(t => t.date_creation).HasColumnName("date_creation");
    }
}
```

And those classes :

```
public partial class util_email
{
    public util_email()
    {
        this.utils = new List<util>();
    }

    public long id_Util_Email { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime date_creation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<util> utils { get; set; }
}
```

So I've tried with Entity Framework Power Tools but the problem is that it generates those classes into a folder which is hard coded in the DLL... So I can't change it :(. And as I've my own architecture (onion architecture), it's a problem.

I've already seen [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171241/entity-framework-power-tools-reverse-engineer-code-first-into-a-folder) but I don't find the answerer's new VSIX...

I'm not closed of any other tool. But this one was convenient for me if I could change the destination folders... I've tried some others but don't manage to do what I want :/

Thanks a lot in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the option **Code First from database** would be the solution:
[image]

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx) is a detailed tutorial about this option.

To generate the models in your desired folder you can right click ond your folder, click add new element and follow the instructions of the tutorial. The models will be generated into the selected folder.

Comment: Hi! Thx for your answer. I've tried this too. I've downloaded the t4 templates but I don't manage to find where I can specify the output folder of my generated classes...

Comment: @fitz_lucassen I updated the answer. Hope this helps you to generate the models without the use of an additional tool.

Comment: That does help indeed but if I want my context to be in a folder and my entities in another one ?

Comment: @fitz_lucassen You can move the context class into another folder and change the namespace. After this you have to edit the app or web.config